# How to unify numbers in prolog?

Tags: prolog

In prolog, if I type `1 is 1.` in the terminal, I get true, but if I try `1 is X.` I get

`ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated`.

But I expect it to tell me all the numbers that are equal to 1, which would only be 1.

How can I unify this?

**(Note: without using `=`)**

Comment: define `unify(X,X).`, but I don't see the point of avoiding unification operator.

Comment: `unify(1,1).` got an error. Function doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an expert, though note that prolog can not and will not unify right hand side of `is`. How do you expect it to unify things like `64 is x*x`?

Rhs of `is` will be explicitly evaluated. You can write something like `X is Y+1` only if `Y` is already unified to some numeric value.

As of your case, `X is 1` will be evaluated ok, while `1 is X` will not.

---

Re-writing the answer of @CapelliC, if you need to avoid using `=` for unification at all costs, the program can look like

```
:- initialization(main).
unify(X,X).
main :- unify(X,1), write(X).
```

Note that it's not the default way: normally you'd use `=`.

So, you have three options:

- Use `=` (preferred)
- Put 1 at the right hand side of `is` (less preferred)
- Use `unify(X,X).` (least preferred)

Answer (score 0):

just to display what I meant in my comment:

```
?- [user].
|: unify(X,X).
|: % user://1 compiled 0,02 sec, 2 clauses
true.

?- unify(1,X).
X = 1.
```